# Use JS Array.Reduce on specific array properties within for-in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, qt, qml

I am trying to use a combination of `Array.reduce` whilst looping through data to provide a result where a value within my array is added together, but only when they also have another matching property, and example of my array is:

```
{"2018":[{"leaveYear":2018,"dayValue":60},{"leaveYear":2018,"dayValue":60}], "2019":[{"leaveYear":2019,"dayValue":60}]}
```

With the above sample, what I want to do is get the sum of each `dayValue`, but only when their `leaveYear` matches. So my result would be:
**2018: 120**
**2019: 60**

This data will then be stored in my database, with the `leaveYear` as the key, and the reduced `dayValue` as the value

**My Progress**
I have started by creating new arrays which group the array objects by `leaveYear`, as they can be of any year, or any order with the function:

```
function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + num;
    }
//used to total my values

function groupBy(array, property) {
        var hash = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (!hash[array[i][property]]) hash[array[i][property]] = [];
            hash[array[i][property]].push(array[i]);
        }
        return hash;
    }
```

Which produces an array of arrays of objects with matching years in each. By then looping over this again, I begin to reduce:

```
var grouped = groupBy(multiSelectSaveArr,'leaveYear')
var multiDeductTotal = []
// my array of arrays by leaveYear

            for(var i in grouped) {
                var splitGroup = grouped[i]
                console.log("SPLITGROUP:" + JSON.stringify(splitGroup))

//my log shows the result of

//SPLITGROUP:[{"leaveYear":2018,"dayValue":60},{"leaveYear":2018,"dayValue":60}]
//SPLITGROUP:[{"leaveYear":2019,"dayValue":60}]
//I then loop through splitGroup to reduce for my desired result by doing the following:

                for(var ix in splitGroup) {
                    multiDeductTotal.push([splitGroup[ix].dayValue])
                }

                var deductReduce = 0 + multiDeductTotal.reduce(getSum)
//signal to database storing data
                calendarPage.amendTakenAllowance(deductReduce, year)
            }
```

**My problem is**
When doing this, there are times this works well, but when more array objects, or several `leaveYears` are added, the loop sometimes seems to skip, or miss numbers, only reducing some, or none the value of a given `leaveYear`

How could I loop over each `leaveYear` of my array, to reduce and send the signal to my database before moving onto the next set of values?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is an object whose values are arrays, and you need to create a new object for every key-value pair in the original object. You can do this by `.map`ping each of the inner arrays to an entry, summing of the `dayValue`s of every item in the array with `.reduce`, and then transforming back into an object with `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const input = {
  "2018": [{
    "leaveYear": 2018,
    "dayValue": 60
  }, {
    "leaveYear": 2018,
    "dayValue": 60
  }],
  "2019": [{
    "leaveYear": 2019,
    "dayValue": 60
  }]
};
const sumDays = yearArr => yearArr.reduce((a, b) => a + b.dayValue, 0);
const output = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.values(input).map(yearArr => ([yearArr[0].leaveYear, sumDays(yearArr)]))
);
console.log(output);
```

If you can't use `fromEntries`, then you can `reduce` into the output object instead:

```js
const input = {
  "2018": [{
    "leaveYear": 2018,
    "dayValue": 60
  }, {
    "leaveYear": 2018,
    "dayValue": 60
  }],
  "2019": [{
    "leaveYear": 2019,
    "dayValue": 60
  }]
};
const sumDays = yearArr => yearArr.reduce((a, b) => a + b.dayValue, 0);
const output = Object.values(input).reduce((a, yearArr) => {
  a[yearArr[0].leaveYear] = sumDays(yearArr);
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am unable to work with the arrow functions `=>`, I am building my app in `Felgo` Formerly `V-Play`, and am currently trying to adjust this to get working (not very good with the arrows), I will mark as answered once I have done so! I am working on the `reduce` suggestion instead of `fromEntries` also! Thanks a million!

Comment: It's generally a good idea to write in the latest and greatest version of the language, and then transpile down for ES5 compatibility automatically with a tool like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/). This lets you write neat, concise code, while still allowing obsolete browsers to understand it.

Comment: Plugging the code into Babel gives me `var sumDays = function sumDays(yearArr) {
  return yearArr.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a + b.dayValue;
  }, 0);
};

var output = Object.values(input).reduce(function (a, yearArr) {
  a[yearArr[0].leaveYear] = sumDays(yearArr);
  return a;
}, {});`

Comment: Babel...I have just discovered something amazing. Thanks for the tip on that! It's definitely a lot more readable for me - and makes sense to write new and then work down!

Comment: Note that Felgo is not stopping you from using arrow functions, you just need Qt 5.12 or later